# node cli - require file before running another

Tags: javascript, node.js, istanbul

So I have a `setup.js` file that I would like to execute/setup for another file.

Currently the setup file is just simply this:

```
require("module-alias/register")
```

However, it may expand in the future which is why I'm asking this question.

I'm wondering if it's possible to `require` or execute the file to setup variables, etc. while executing another,

(just an example from nyc, i'd like to know if `node` itself can do this):

```
nyc mocha-webpack --require ./tests/setup.js ./tests/unit/$FILE"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `--require` or `-r` can be passed as a parameter to node, and it loads the module using the same logic as the `require()` call. Check the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_r_require_module) for details.

`--require` is also implemented as an option to `nyc` as you pointed out, and mentioned in [their documentation](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#require-additional-modules)

Comment: I was probably a bit unclear. I was wondering if `node` (not `nyc`) had a `require` like parameter. Just don't want to put the `require("module-alias/register")` at the top of every file.

Comment: @A.Lau my bad, I reverted that title edit and updated my answer